# Hyperlink relative paths to files in points layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, html, jpg, hyperlink, file-path

I would like to add hyperlinks to each point in a points layer in QGIS 1.7.0 running on Mac OS X 10.6.7, but I have several requirements:

(1) Each hyperlink has to be a relative path to the linked file.

(2) The linked files are mainly JPEG images, but may occasionally be HTML files. Either way, I want them to open upon click in the OS's default image/html viewer, regardless of what computer I open it on.

(3) The linked filenames are already specified in a column in the point layer's attribute table. I want to use those filenames in they hyperlinks so I don't have to manually type in a path for each point (there are several hundred points, each pointing to a different file).

How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) and (2) are possible with eVis plugin ([Documentation](http://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/evis/documentation.php#d0e390)).

Ad (3): You should be able to use Field Calculator to add the path to the filenames you already in attribute table. Field calculator is described here: http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Calculating_field_values. You can use + operator to concatenate strings.

Comment: That's great. Can you be a little more specific about how I should use the field calculator? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What is the bigger picture problem you are trying to solve?

Maybe you want to have geolocated images as a starting point, and let that be the basis for the spatial catalogue?

see http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Creating_geo-referenced_photos_for_display_in_QGIS

Comment: The info contained in the link is great, but the Geosetter software is Windows only. Is there a way to do this on a Mac and Linux system? Thanks.