# Is there a way of viewing a photo has a point tag from Photo2shape in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, imagery

Is there a way to view images (photos) that have location point from Photo2shape by clicking on the point in QGIS?

Comment: Ryan Answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can then use the "[eVis](http://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/evis/)" plugin to set up hotlinks to the photos themselves, and launch a photo viewer by clicking on the attribute field.

See similar questions at:

- [How can I import georeferenced photos (jpg, kml, kmz) using QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23698/how-can-i-import-georeferences-photos-jpg-kml-kmz-in-qgis-arcgis)
- [Hyperlink relative paths to files in points layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/hyperlink-relative-paths-to-files-in-points-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: This is helpful to view the photo. My question was not clear - we need to see the foot print of the image (aerial photograph) or images to see how they overlay.

Comment: Mark, I would suggest you mark this answer as accepted and open a new question that asks your second question, "how to identify image footprints of an aerial photograph".  You will likely get better answers with that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ImportPhotos Plug-in: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ImportPhotos/